# Add rows to table which it contains a text box and an image in a same column and onclick that image calender must opens

Tags: javascript

Am new to javascript .... Here am trying to add or remove extra rows for the given input box,and a calendar image ... When clicking the calender image the calender must opens ... and after selecting the date it automatically fills the input box ... how to do that ... Please help me...

```
  <html>
    <head>

    <script language="javaScript" type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>
       <link href="calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script>

        function addRowToTable()
    {
      var tbl = document.getElementById('tblsample');
      var name=document.getElementById('accounthead1');
      var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
      var iteration = lastRow-1;
      var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

        function addImageRolled(src) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.onclick= setYears('2010', '2025').showCalender(this, 'billdate');
        }
      var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
      var e2 = document.createElement('input');

      e2.type = 'text';
      e2.readOnly = true;
      e2.name = 'billdate' + iteration;
      e2.id = 'billdate' + iteration;
      e2.size = 8;


    //  e2.onkeyup = keyPressTest;
    //  e1.value=iteration;
      cellRight.appendChild(e2).appendChild(addImageRolled('calender.png'));

    }
    function removeRow()
    {
    var tbl=document.getElementById("tblsample");
    var lastRow=tbl.rows.length-1;
     if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
     <table id="tblsample" width="100" height="100"><tr>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="billdate" readonly="" id="billdate"  size="8"><a href="#" onClick="setYears(2010, 2025);
           showCalender(this, 'billdate');">
          <img src="calender.png"></a></td></tr></table>

    <table align="right">
      <tr><th colspan="1"><input type="button" value="  +  " style="background-color:#cacc82" onclick="addRowToTable();" /><input type="button" value="  -  " style="background-color:#cacc82" onclick="removeRow();" /></th></tr>
     </table>
<table id="calenderTable">
        <tbody id="calenderTableHead">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center">
              <select onChange="showCalenderBody(createCalender(document.getElementById('selectYear').value,
               this.selectedIndex, false));" id="selectMonth">
                  <option value="0">Jan</option>
                  <option value="1">Feb</option>
                  <option value="2">Mar</option>
                  <option value="3">Apr</option>
                  <option value="4">May</option>
                  <option value="5">Jun</option>
                  <option value="6">Jul</option>
                  <option value="7">Aug</option>
                  <option value="8">Sep</option>
                  <option value="9">Oct</option>
                  <option value="10">Nov</option>
                  <option value="11">Dec</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <select onChange="showCalenderBody(createCalender(this.value, 
                document.getElementById('selectMonth').selectedIndex, false));" id="selectYear">
                </select>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <a href="#" onClick="closeCalender();"><font color="#003333" size="+1">X</font></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tbody id="calenderTableDays">
         <tr style="">
           <td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tue</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thu</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tbody id="calender"></tbody>
    </table>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just vote on reopen, user3345502. I also  think it is not necessarily a duplicate, but there must be 5 reopen votes to get it reopened, so it may or may not be.

Comment: @FinalContest I can't Do it ...... Need help from other 5